# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: xx, Size: xx

Tags: java

I am loading a .csv file with comma delimiter by using jdom parser to split the data and insert into database.

but somehow I have hit this error as title mentioned. 
the .csv file contains of over 200k of records.

when it reads until around 4000 records , the program was thrown this error. 
index and size are the same value but before that all the records can be inserted successfully. Just wondering why it goes until almost 4k only hit this error.

this is my for loop :

```
for(int x = 0; x < FLODS.getBufferSize(); x++)
```

But I did a search on internet : they are sugguesting this method..

```
for(int x = 0; x < FLODS.getBufferSize()-1; x++)
```

Any idea? Thanks :)

Comment: We need to see the code inside the for loop and the line which throws the error

Comment: What is loop body.  Which line exception is thrown?

Answer (score 7):

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: xx, Size: xx`

A very common `Exception`. This clearly states that you're trying to access an **Index** of `xx`, where the **Size** of the `ArrayList`(for example) is also `xx`. Always remember that if the size is `xx`, you can access the index only till `xx-1`. If you try to access `xx` index, where the size is also `xx`, you are bound to get this error.

Hence the suggestion from **Internet**, asking you to traverse only till `-1` of whatever size.

Though your `FOR` loop seems to be okay, but may be your are trying to access some index inside the loop which is `1` more than the current `x` value at some point.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException is a type of exception that appears when index of some sort (such as to an array, to a string, or to a vector) is out of range so check for the memory allotted.
that's all one can say without viewing the code before and within the for loop

Answer (score 0):

This is a mistake when you have a nested For loop and try to access the 1st variable in the second one.

```
for(int i = 0;i<something.size(); i++) {
     //Some manipulations here..
     for(int j = 0;j<somethingElse.size(); j++) {
          //using blah(i) instead of blah(j) causes this issue
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> div1=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='art_title']"));        

for(int i=0;i<=div1.size();i++)
{           
    System.out.println(div1.get(i).getText());          
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Instead of the above format I changed it into this format:

```
List<WebElement> div1=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='art_title']"));
String[] abc = new String[div1.size()];

int i= 0;

for (WebElement e : div1) 
{
        abc[i] = e.getText();
        i++;            
        System.out.println(e.getText());
}
```