# IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, element

I am creating a simple game where 2 players take coins from piles. The piles are each element of an array lists and the amount of coins for each pile are the Integers stored in them like this.

3 piles of varying coin values:

[4,5,2]

But I am running into this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
```

Here is my method

```
static void removeCoinsAt(int index, int numCoins){
    //exception on this line
    coins.set(index, coins.get(index) - numCoins);
    for(int i = 0; i < coins.size(); i ++){
        int val = coins.get(i);
        if (val == 0) {
            coins.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This happens even when index = 3 and numCoins = 2. I've tried adding -1 to the index on either

```
coins.set(index-1, coins.get(index-1) - numCoins);
```

But I still run into this error one way or another. I know the Arraylist counts its elements from 0 and I've looked over these solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044242/why-is-my-arraylist-out-of-bounds-index-3-size-3-when-i-call-this-method), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460258/java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-invalid-index-2-size-is-2), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205098/java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-index-xx-size-xx) but I still can't quite figure it out.

Comment: how size of your coins array?? is it 3?

Comment: Check the line where you have an error (you will find it in error response), and then think a moment, why there is an error and why such a value is in a place with error. It's really not so difficult in this method, and when you want to get a programming sense, the first thing you have to do is to find and correct self errors. Yes this is a place to ask for difficulties, but after you will try to beat problems by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list with three elements. Those elements are at indexes `0`, `1` and `2`. You call `removeCoinsAt(3, 2)`. Your method says `coins.set(index, coins.get(index) - numCoins);`. That means it is trying to get and set the value at index `3`, an index that does not exist in the list.

Obviously you can't adjust the value at an index that is past the end of the list, and you know the list index only goes as high as 2. So why would you expect `removeCoinsAt(3, 2)` to work?